# Phonegap update installed plugins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have this phonegap application and installed some plugins (like Camera plugin). All is well, until I need to make an adjustment on the platforms supported to it.

Unfortunately, I can't see the adjustments each platform when I run the command `phonegap build <platform>`. What seems to be the problem? Do I need to copy and paste the code on the different platforms?

Comment: Do you mean that you've made adjustments in the platfoms inside plugins folder, and they're not showing in the project>platforms>(ios,android.. etc.) folder? You need to make the changes inside the project>platforms>(ios,android.. etc.) not plugins>pluginName>...

Comment: I see. So what's the proper way to install and update the plugin?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell you the proper way or best way. I can just tell you the way I use. If i need to update any plugin I simply uninstall the plugin and re-install it. If I need to make any change inside plugin by my own, then I find those plugin files inside `platforms` folder for each platform, and modify it.